# How do I watch data series on highmaps?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

Here I want to ask how do I watch data from highmaps?

In this case the data in this series appears when first accessed.

But when I refresh the data page it doesn't load successfully.

This is the code that I made.

**Maps.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div id="container">
        <highcharts :constructor-type="'mapChart'" :options="mapOptions"></highcharts>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'indonesia',
    props: ["chartData"],
    data () {
        return {
            mapOptions: {
                chart: {
                    map: 'myMapName'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js">World, Miller projection, medium resolution</a>'
                },
                mapNavigation: {
                    enabled: true,
                    buttonOptions: {
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    }
                },

                colorAxis: {
                    min: 0
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                series: [{
                    data: this.chartData,
                    name: 'Random data',
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            color: '#BADA55'
                        }
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.name}'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
#container {
    height: auto !important;
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

**index.vue**

```html
<tempplate>
    <v-container>
        <v-row>
            <v-col
                sm="12"
                md="6"
                lg="6"
            >
                <maps :chartData="getUserChartByProvince"></maps>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</tempplate>
<script>
    import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'
    import moment from 'moment'
    import _ from 'lodash'

    import Maps from '@/views/Maps'

    export default {
        name: 'Dashboard',
        components: {
            Maps,
        },
        data () {
            return {
                loaded: false,
            }
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters('chart', [
                'getUserChartByProvince'
            ]),
            ...mapGetters('location', ['getSelectedCities']),
        },
        created () {
            this.locationSummary()
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions('location', ['locationSummary'])
        }
    }
</script>
```

If someone knows please explain how this should work.

I would be happier if someone explained it too.

Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @Mochamad Akbar, Please reproduce the problem in some online code editor. You can use: https://codesandbox.io/s/

Comment: @ppotaczek ,sorry for the late response.I have found the solution. just add this `this.mapOptions.series[0].data = this.chartData;` to be mounted. thanks :)